# JAVA GUI closing frame and opening exactly the same one (resetting)

Tags: java, user-interface

Im working on a simple Java GUI game (please check the attachment) Ive created 4 classes, 3 classes create 3 different panels (red, green and yellow) and 4th class joins them together into one frame.
Now, I need after pressing the button "Play a Game" to reset, re open the whole frame, making new session for a player.
At the moment I manage to create whole new MainFrame frame, but the old stays, is there any chance to fix it without completely changing my GUI code structure? Ive tried different methods, but as I lack experience, none of them did work.

Screenshot of GUI:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/FbpZUpGX125j7R3c9

main frame code:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

private JFrame frame = new JFrame("No name at the moment");

public MainFrame(){
    frame.setSize(840, 220);
    frame.setLayout (new GridLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    makeFrame();
}
public void makeFrame(){
    frame.add(new PanelA());
    frame.add(new PanelB());
    frame.add(new PanelC());
}
```

And the PanelB class with button listener:

```
public PanelB()
{
    setLayout (new GridLayout());
    setBackground(Color.GREEN);
    setVisible(true);
    makePanelB();

}

public void makePanelB()
{
    JButton buttonPlayAgame = new JButton("Play a game");
    buttonPlayAgame.addActionListener(source -> new MainFrame() );

    JButton buttonExit = new JButton("Exit"); 
    buttonExit.addActionListener(source -> System.exit(0));

    add(panelB);
    panelB.add(buttonPlayAgame);
    panelB.add(buttonExit);
    panelB.add(outputMessage, new FlowLayout());
    panelB.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jay. Do I understand your question correct: You want to dispose the current `MainFrame` an create a new one, when the user clicks the button `buttonPlayAgame`?

Comment: Yes, I need to dispose of old MainFrame and open new MainFrame after activating buttonPlayAgame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `dispose()` the current JFrame before calling `new MainFrame()`.
Change the ActionListener of your `buttonPlayAgame` button to the following:

```
buttonPlayAgame.addActionListener(source ->  {
    JFrame currentFrame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(panelB); // Get the reference of the current frame (which contains panelB component)
    currentFrame.dispose(); // Dispose the current frame
    new MainFrame(); // Create new frame
});
```

Comment: Sebastian !!!!THANK YOU!!!! Ive spent so many hours trying to fix this problem...

Comment: @Jay. Glad I could help you. Would you please mark this answer as accepted if it fixes your problem?

Comment: Sebastian, sorry, I did, but thats what I get: <<Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.>>

Comment: Hi @Jay. It appears that you try to [upvote this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400), which is not necessary. To [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Accepting an answer indicates that you've found a solution to your problem and gives both of us some reputation.